# Double BiQuad sector antenna

Tags: wireless, antenna

I want to DIY a double BiQuad antenna . But I find they are different from different web. As the picture first of below, the board under the antenna is flat, but the second has two orthogonal bend. I just want high dBi and use for  5.8G wireless image transmission. Which is better ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: usually, *it depends* applies, especially to antenna design.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  I want DIY antenna for 5.8G wireless image transmission. Which is suitable? I just know how to calculate the parameter of second antenna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metal plane really just has the purpose of acting as a reflector – due to symmetry, the biquad has the same pattern into the "front" and back, and adding a simple metal plane in the right distance from the antenna will make the reflections add up constructively with the "forward" direction, thus adding a 3dB to gain (in theory).

You want an infinitely sized, perfectly conducting ground plane. You don't get that, but something around two times the quad side length in each direction around the driven element should do *most* of the work – you don't lose that much if you don't have that.

The bent "legs" might have the purpose of electrically "enlarging" the plane area, but they might also serve as mechanical improvements, making the ground plane more rigid.

I'd recommend simulating this stuff – OpenEMS, free as it is, already comes with a Biquad example, and you'd only need to add a reflector to that and play with the parameters.

The problem I often encounter when researching this kind of question is that many Antenna "theory" on the internet is written by Hams that assume that SWR (standing wave ratio) is the final and best and only measure for antenna quality, totally ignoring that an impedance-matched terminator has perfect SWR; so for example, I found one source that claimed that a driven element-plane distance that would lead to destructive interference is the optimal configuration – probably just because he saw a better impedance matching that way. But that's the dominant quality of antenna discussions – based on not-really-understood measures and vague heuristics rather than actual simulation and understanding :(

Comment: In fact , I don't know what is impedance matching. Do you mean I should use 50 Ohm feeder line ?  But how do know it just be 50 Ohm ?

Comment: I don't know your equipment, but 50 Ω is the most common impedance in microwave equipment, yes. An antenna is technically but an impedance transformer between your transmission line and the free-space impedance, so matching an antenna design to your line is crucial. Now, for transmit only, if you're not planning to use significant power and if your TX amplifier can withstand a bit of reflection, a perfect match isn't *strictly necessary*, but you'd waste power on energy being reflected back into the cable.

Comment: What equipment can do this ? I just have a multimeter.

Comment: To actually measure wave impedance, you'd need a microwave network analyzer. You won't be able to afford one. A SWR meter is just as good for that purpose – anyway, your TX amplifier definitely will have a spec that says whether it uses 50, 75 Ω or any other impedance, and so do the cables you can buy. And the wave impedance is a function of your design – so that should be spec'ed somewhere, too!

Answer (score 2):

[**Here's**](http://buildyourownantenna.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/double-biquad-antenna-calculator.html) a calculator for the version with the bended earth plane (see LH dimension in diagram below): -

[image]

So I would contact the guy who posted this blog to get more details of the radiation pattern. I don't think anyone on here will know this without such a consulation. The blog has a comment section that appears to have been used as recently as February this year.

Comment: The font of the title reminds me of some famous antenna calculator collection website, where I think that blog simply stole that – but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller no bells ringing for me!

Comment: @MarcusMüller  what is the famous antenna calculator collection website ?

Comment: I'm thinking really hard here

Comment: It's not http://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/bi_quad_antenna_designer.php

Comment: maybe that blog *is* the original source, and what I remember was just a more-or-less honest collection of such calculators

Comment: I had the same idea but instead of using a biquad element I substituted a wireless cellular modem and used the dimensions for that modem @ 2100 Mhz- works well.